# Attempting to submit a form to Node backend

Tags: node.js

I have a simple username and password form.

```html
<div action = "/authenticate" class = "container center_div" id="loginForm" method="get">

            <p> Enter username and password</p>
            <form name="credentials">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginCredentials">Log In</button>

            </form>

        </div>
```

I am expecting after clicking the submit button to see the username and password on the `Node` side.

However, when I do:

```js
app.get('/authenticate', (req, res)=> {
    console.log("API request for authenticate")
    console.log(req);
});
```

I don't see anything on console after submitting the form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is strange that you set the attributes on the div insted of the form

this should work better :

```
<form action = "/authenticate" class = "container center_div" id="loginForm" method="get">
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, you should not submit a form with a GET method. you should change the method to **POST** and in your backend code , change `app.get` to `app.post` and you should be good.

**Additional changes to make your code work better*

***Add:*** : `name="username"` to your first input field and
***Add:*** `name="password"` to your second input field

you can then

```js
console.log(req.body.username) // this will print out the username
console.log(req.body.password) // this will print out the password
```